# Multi-part identifier could not be bound with basic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

I am scratching my head with the following very basic query (part of a much more complex query), where I get an error simply for using the alias I defined for a table. I was running the query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v17.5, I upgraded to v17.7 but it didn't make a difference.

Why do these three versions of the query work fine

```
SELECT Top(3) AddressNumber from [char_test1].[dbo].[test1_READY]
SELECT Top(3) AddressNumber from [char_test1].[dbo].[test1_READY] AS Ε
SELECT Top(3) [AddressNumber] from [char_test1].[dbo].[test1_READY] AS Ε
```

While these three versions

```
SELECT Top(3) E.[AddressNumber] from [char_test1].[dbo].[test1_READY] AS Ε
SELECT Top(3) [E].[AddressNumber] from [char_test1].[dbo].[test1_READY] AS Ε
SELECT Top(3) [E].[AddressNumber] from [char_test1].[dbo].[test1_READY] AS [Ε]
```

give error

> The multi-part identifier "E.AddressNumber" could not be bound.

(Obviously I don't need an alias here, but as I said this is the stripped-down version of a larger query with many tables, just to replicate the error)

[ UPDATE ]

Problem solved, thanks to a remark by @Gordon-Linoff.
Turns out that I had copied the second group of queries from somewhere else, and the "E" character was identical to an "E" but had a different ASCII code.
I checked it with python Spyder:

```
ord('Ε')
Out[110]: 917
ord('E')
Out[111]: 69
```

Comment: It's worth noting that "SQL Server Management Studio" is not an RDBMS, it's an application. SQL server is an RDBMS. When you upgraded the version of SSMS, you didn't upgrade your RDBMS, so you shouldn't expect any changes to your SQL's behaviour.

Comment: Share the original/whole query.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, well pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have written the question, all six statements should work identically . . . assuming that `AddressNumber` is in `[char_test1].[dbo].[test1_READY]`.

My guess is that you have another table in the `FROM` when you actually run the queries.  That table contains `AddressNumber`.

Another (rather remote) possibility is that you have another character that is invisible around the `E` either in the alias definition or in the alias reference.  If that is the case, then retyping the code will fix the problem.

Comment: Unbelievable! Thanks @Gordon-Linoff, your comment about the "rather remote" possibility made me check the characters. Turns out that I had copied the query from somewhere else and that "E" was not what it looked like! Using python I checked the ASCII value of the "E" in the query, and compared it with an "E" that I typed:
ord('Ε')
Out[110]: 917
ord('E')
Out[111]: 69